# Strange behaviour of C pointers with memory mapped I/O

Tags: c, pointers, kernel, osdev

I am currently working on writing a basic operating system as a learning project. I use a gcc 4.9.2 cross compiler for this purpose.
When trying to use memory-mapped I/O I stumbled upon behaviour of C pointers (or possibly memory-mapped I/O) which I fail to understand.
When directly accessing the I/O memory through following code, I get the expected result, which is an "AB" in the top left corner in light grey font on black background.

```
*((uint16_t *)0xB8000) = 0x0741;
*((uint16_t *)0xB8002) = 0x0742;
```

However when trying to manipulate the memory through the use of an offset adding 2 to the base address the result is not as expected an "A" in second but in third position.

```
*((uint16_t *)0xB8000 + 2) = 0x0741;
```

Adding 1 instead of 2 prints out the letter in second position, however I do not understand why. Since every letter (in MMIO) is composed of 2 bytes of data I would assume that I need to increase the memory address which I write to by 2 for the next character. (As I did at first by writing directly to 0xB8002)
In order to try and understand this behaviour I did some testing in a separate C program but was unable to replicate this behaviour:
(Note: This code was compiled using normal gcc 4.8.2)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void) {
        printf("0xB8000 + 1 = %x\n", 0xB8000 + 1);
        printf("&(*(uint16_t *)(0xB8000 + 1)) = %x\n", (uint32_t)&(*(uint16_t *)(0xB8000 + 1)));
}
```

This program produced following output:

```
0xB8000 + 1 = b8001
&(*(uint16_t *)(0xB8000 + 1)) = b8001
```

I assume that I am missing some kind of behaviour of C pointers which causes the factoring in of the size of data which is written by a statement. Is this the case or is there a different reason that I have overlooked?

Regards, Kenshooak

Comment: You might benefit from re-reading pointer-arithmetic basics (always scaled by the underlying type). Or maybe operator-precedence (cast has higher precedence than `+`).

Comment: Also, you might want to use `volatile` here to make sure the compiler doesn't try to be smart and optimize the assignments away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add an integer `n` to a `<type>` pointer the address is incremented by `sizeof( <type> ) * n` bytes.
So in your first example, you have

```
*((uint16_t *)0xB8000 + 2) = 0x0741;
```

so what happens here is: 0xB8000 is cast to `unit16_t *` and then that pointer is incremented by 2 which means `2 * sizeof( uint16_t )` = 4 Bytes

In your second example you have

```
 *(uint16_t *)(0xB8000 + 1)
```

Notice the different bracketing: here you first add 1 to 0xB8000 -- a simple integer operation -- and cast the result.

Comment: Thank you very much, I absolutely missed that the different bracketing might have an effect on the result!